# jQuery Validation - live validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery Validation [DOCS](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate).

Just wondering, can we do a validation onfocusout before submitting the form? There is an option in the spec - but works only after you firstly submit the form.

What I'm trying to achive - as you want to go offfocus - it will mark input as valid(check) or not valid(error msg).

Currently functionality is there but only after you submit the form.

My Validation code:

```
$('.loginbox').validate({
        debug: true,
        rules: {
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8,
                maxlength: 8
            },
            username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2 
            }
        },
        showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
            this.defaultShowErrors();
        },
        success: "valid",
        submitHandler: function() { alert("Submitted!") }
    });
```

Any help much appreciated. Pete

Comment: Pete if I was any help could you throw a checkmark on my answer?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a text input is valid according to the validation plugin, it creates a label class of error valid.

```
<label class="error valid" for="spill" generated="generated"></label>
```

Use CSS tp pick up on this like this

```
label.error:before {
content:        "\0020 \2718 \0020"; // is an X
color:          red;
}


label.error {
    padding-left: 16px;  
    margin-left: .3em;
}
label.valid {
    display: block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
label.valid:before {
content:       "\0020 \2714"; // Is a Checkmark
color:          green;
```

}

Of course instead of entities you can use img's as well. On Error this will show an X as well as the message you devise in the validation.
. On success and as you leave the text input this will also leave a check mark under the input.

You might also want to use messages in validator like this

```
$("#upd").rules("add", {
        required: true,
        minlength: 1,
        maxlength: 1,
    messages: {
        required: "Please pick a category",
        minlength: jQuery.format("Please, Check at least one box"),
        maxlength: jQuery.format("Please, You checked too many boxes"),
    }
});
```